# How to get real source address of a packets in NAT'd VM

Tags: nat, ssh, network-discovery

Host OS Ubuntu with live IP address 1.2.3.4 .

And a Ubuntu VM running in Virtual Box with NAT network configuration. I need to SSH my VM from external network with IP address 3.3.3.3 . So I configure port forwarding on my host.

With this configuration I successfully SSH my VM from external IP 3.3.3.3 at IP address 1.2.3.4 . When I check auth.log of VM to have a look on SSH logs, Their was no SSH connection entry from IP 3.3.3.3 . All connection was established on 10.0.2.2. But real IP of all connections is 3.3.3.3 . I have some use cases for which real Source Address is important.

I am wondering if i could find a way to have a real source IP of connection.

I have not strong knowledge of Networks, I am a student of networks. So I apologize in advance if you feel difficulty in understanding or you found this basic. **And I would be greatly thankful if you could suggest me alternative**.

Update: I done port forwarding with help of this [link](https://nsrc.org/workshops/2014/btnog/raw-attachment/wiki/Track2Agenda/ex-virtualbox-portforward-ssh.htm)

Use Case: 
I have deployed SSH Honeypots in my VM. Any one who will try to SSH my Live IP 1.2.3.4 at port 22, will be forwarded to SSH honeypot. In honeypot VM all SSH sessions are logged. So in logs I need the real IP of attacker(3.3.3.3).

Update:
Sorry i forgot to mention, I have also added port 2222 in ssh config (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) of my VM. And command I use for SSh `#ssh vmusername@1.2.3.4 -p 2222`

Comment: What is your host os?

Comment: @PeterGreen I have mentioned in my Question.

Comment: VM and server configurations, and protocols above OSI layer 4, are all Questions about explicitly off topic here. This question should be asked on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect the best approach here would be to forget using the built in NAT in virtualbox and instead set up a host only network and then use standard iptables NAT on the host.

Comment: You can elaborate your answer?

Comment: I have configured host only. Now my VM have IP address `192.168.56.101`, I successfully SSH my VM from host. But when i move forward, I implement IPTables rule to forward traffic from host to VM. It is not working. I enable IP forwarding at host with `#sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`, and add `#iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.56.101:2222` to /etc/iptables/rules.v4. Now when I ssh my VM from external network.`#ssh vmusername@1.2.3.4`, No output. also No logs on my host 1.2.3.4 and in VM also.  
I  setup NAT for VM to communicate back to world.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me on this. If you are feeling cumbersome in understanding, do mention so I could update my question.

Comment: Umm unless you have special config on the client ssh vmusername@1.2.3.4 will connect to port 22 not port 2222

Comment: Right but you also have to tell the client what port to connect to.

Comment: can you post the output of iptables -L and iptables -t NAT -l on the host?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36173/discussion-between-hackingnerd-and-peter-green).

Comment: I have changed my IPTable forwarding policy you point out previously, But still same issue. No response. Please have a look in chat, I have shared my current rules.